# pyScript working with raw_input but nor with an assignment

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to control a relay box using pySerial.

using this code it works if I input a 'd'which turn on the relay

```
port = "COM3"
ser = serial.Serial(port)
print ser.name + ' is open'
cmd = raw_input("Enter a command  ")
print cmd
ser.write(cmd.emcode('ascii')+'\r\n')
```

but if I try

```
cmd = 'd'
```

rather than via the raw_input it does not work.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks Andrew

The code that did not work was

```
port = "COM3"
ser = serial.Serial(port)
print ser.name + ' is open'
cmd = 'd'
print cmd
ser.write(cmd.encode('ascii')+'\r\n')
```

Regards Andrew

It looks like an i/o issue. I found just using

```
test = raw_input('test')
cmd = 'd'
```

worked it seems a raw_input is needed for reasons I don't understand.

Regards Andrew

Final update it was the delay caused by the raw_input rather that the input that allowed it to work. By adding delays it now works as expected.

Comment: Did you mean `cmd.encode`? Did you test this exact code? Can you also post the exact code that failed? It should work, so its something in the details.

Comment: They look like they should have identical results. I can't explain it.

Comment: Sorry about the mess above I am new to the forum.It looks like a type issue in that after doing the cmd = raw_input("text") I can change the value of cmd say cmd = 'e' and it works